# Document.ready and a code that appears after it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modal plugin on my page that shouts on `$(document).ready` but i also have another function (`innerHTML`) which puts the `<a>` 5-10 seconds after the page has been loaded, this way the modal doesn't work cause it's only working on the code that was there before it has been loaded.

I was thinking about making a function that will "click" on an existing `<a>` can it be done?
basically i need that when the `<a>` will appear it will open up the modal instead of going to `chat.php`

```
<a href=\"chat.php\" class=\"iframe\">
```

any help?

Comment: So you have a modal being displayed followed by an anchor tag that gets displayed after the modal? Have you ever tried binding the display of the modal window event to the load event of the page? This way it's guaranteed that all elements will be rendered.

Comment: that's the problem they are all rendered but the `<a>` I'm talking about is inserted to the page like 10 seconds after everything is loaded up.

Comment: in your case, in document ready you can use $('a[href=chat.php]').live('click',function(){ ... }); and that will surely work. or just add some class to your <a> and then use that class to live event.

Comment: Like i said I'm not a js pro and this seems to be really confusing.
do i need to do that like the following? `$('a[href=chat.php]').live('click',function(){ $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"540px", height:"570px"}); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `bind` method, or directly use `onclick` on your selectors, it will attach event to that specific control only if selector has results. Try to do same thing using `live` method, it will remember your event attachment even if your selector doesn't have any results, and if same kind of control is added later on, that event is automatically bonded to that control.

for example, if you are using 
`$('#btnSubmit').click(function(){ ... );` in document.ready replace it with $('#btnSubmit').live('click',function(){...}); this will fire click event even if you add btnSubmit after page load.

Comment: That's what I was going to suggest, but the event should be different - maybe load on the anchor tag?

Comment: that's right, this is just an example, you can use any event that is supported by jQuery

Comment: thanks but what about `$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"540px", height:"570px"});`? I'm sorry but I'm not a js pro and i have just tried like 4 different variations with `.live` and it didn't worked out, do i need to put it outside of the `document.ready`?

Comment: Hi, If the code $('.iframe').colorbox is showing modal popup, move it to click event of <a> tab, if you want to show it when <a> tag is clicked.